# Databricks write config file to dbfs:/

Tags: pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks

Is it possible to write/modify (aka vim) file at dbfs:/ using databricks-cli or UI?
I don't have an option to write this file from the notebook directly.

Example:
I need to create .ini file, put properties here, and later read them from a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [databricks-cli copy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli#copy-a-file) to put the configuration file there. This way you can also fetch existing files, modify it and move it back to DBFS.

I don't exactly know your use case, but that is the most straightforward way of solving this. At my company, this is our standard approach for shipping configurations files to Databricks (we do this from the CI/CD).

Alternatively, [dbx](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html) might be interesting to look at. It's based around the `databricks-cli` and makes shipping your project and dependencies easier. Since I don't know your use case, I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: first link is wrong

Comment: i didn't spot that cp command from CLI actually moves files from local env to dbfs. this resolves all my issues. Thanks!

note: first link is wrong

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect link, I've updated the answer! I'm glad it worked.